# Different Unwind Segue depending on source

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a 'Master' `UITableViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController` and a 'Detail' `UIViewController`.

On the Master nav bar, I have an 'add' button which segues to the Detail view which has a Save & Cancel button on the nav bar.

The table cells also segue to the same Detail view and passes the data in the `prepareForSegue` method.

The unwind segue method for the save button in Detail View needs to either:

1. Add new row to Master table if add button was used to show Detail view or
2. Modify the data for the selected row if it was used to present the Detail view

What I can't figure out is how to distinguish between the two sources in the unwind method...

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a 'source' parameter to the 'Detail' view controller, and give it a  value when you segue to it. This can be done in the prepareForSegue method:

```
DetailViewController* destinationController = (DetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
destinationController.source = value
```

And then you can take actions according to the value of the source. This is probably not the most elegant way, but it should work.

---EDIT:---

You can also try using [self presentingViewController]  if your 'Detail' view controller is presented modally. This should give you the view controller that presented it, and you can try differentiating using isKindOfClass maybe?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that but it seems like such a common thing to do, there would be a better solution...

Comment: I have made an edit to the answer, but the alternative method can only be used with modal view controllers.